# Is there a way to merge columns via the Reports/Visualization Screen?

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to find a simpler way to combine column values in my visual. I need a total column for certain values. If my data was stored the way my visual is presented that would be simple, but in order to change this in power query, it looks like I will either need a complex function or unpivot my data in a new table in order to make a column for each Category so I can merge columns with the transform tool.

How my data is in the Table/query:

| Category | Values | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category 1 | $Value 1 | Dept 1 |
| Category 2 | $Value 2 | Dept 2 |

*cont'd for 1500 rows with ~20 categories and 8 departments*

My Visual is a matrix table:

|  | Category 1 | Category 2 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dept 1 | $value | $ Value |  |
| Dept 2 | $value | $ Value |  |
| Total |  |  |  |

I have tried to create a measure to add the 3 columns i need together, but I don't think I did it correctly. I attempted a Calculate Function, but could not figure out how to filter where it only sums the 3 categories I need, it only wanted to filter one value.

I would love it if there was a simple way to just merge the 2 columns in the visual into one without having to edit my query itself. I am pretty new to PowerBI, so apologies if this has been asked before or is a simple fix.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You write *`create a measure to add the 3 columns I need`*. What three columns? Then you write about *`a simple way to just merge the 2 columns `*. And you are also trying to get a `Total` which implies an addition operation, not a merge operation. Please be more specific. BTW, in Power Query it would seem pretty simple to create a table like your Visual using the `Table.Group` method, but better examples with more realistic samples along with a screenshot of what you expect as an output from those samples would be useful.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Power BI supports column grouping. I bet you could group row-wise by department and the column-wise by category to push the category values out. In the category row footer, you could add a SUM() to aggregate the value.

Comment: Could you please show the measure you created along with expected vs. actual results?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to make things unnecessarily complicated. Power BI uses "implicit measures" if necessary, so you don't have to worry about DAX:

With the Matrix visual pull 'Table'[Department] onto the Rows field, 'Table'[Category] onto Columns and 'Table'[Values] onto the Values field.

[image]

[image]